# Android ffmpeg video cut

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I´m trying to edit some videos in my Android app using FFmpeg, but I´m facing some problems when I tried to take just a part of the video.

I´m using this ffmpeg compilation/lib https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

I tried to use this command to trim/cut the video

```
"-y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.00 -t 00:00:15.000 -c copy output.mp4"
```

But with some videos I´m getting a black screen or the video just freezes. The sound works fine in all my tests.

With this command

```
"-y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -t 00:00:15.000 -async 1 output.mp4"
```

Everything works fine in all my tests (video/sound) but takes too much time to generate the output file, this 15s file takes more than 2 minutes to be generated.

I tried other variations of these commands, but I always get problems with the video stream (with black screen or freezing) or takes too much time to generate the output (the user can only select 15s of the videos to send to my server)

Thanks by the help!

EDIT:

this is the part of the code that is trimming the video

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"-y","-i",input,"-ss","00:00:05.000","-vcodec","copy",
            "-acodec","copy","-t","00:00:15.00","-strict","-2",output };

    final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.i("VideoEditActivity", "Success " + message);
                is_video_generated_ = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.i("VideoEditActivity", "Progress updated " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("VideoEditActivity", "ERROR! " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                progress_dialog_.setMessage(getString(R.string.str_video_generating));
                progress_dialog_.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i("VideoEditActivity", "Finished");
                progress_dialog_.hide();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("media", edited_video_path_);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the original file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqJL_nNetbRYmxvcTljanJwR00/view?usp=sharing][1]

And this the output: 0BzqJL_nNetbReENjRGMtVXQ5VHM/view?usp=sharing (stack overflow does not allow me to add more than 2 links)

Comment: When streamcopying, videos can only be trimmed at keyframes.  So, if your `-ss` is `12` and the keyframe is at `10` then the output video will be frozen/black till the next keyframe appears.

Comment: ok, changing the order of the -ss will fix the video frame start (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking), but is there a easy way to trim the end of the video at a keyframe (even that the video will be a little bigger than I need)? I read a little about this, and some guys are using ffprobe to get the keyframes timestamp, but I don't have it in my Android build today.

Answer (score 6):

I had faced the same problem, After digging lot, I have found a perfect solution.

```
 /**
 * Command for cutting video
 */
private void executeCutVideoCommand(long startMs, long endMs) {

    String destPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test/";//Replace ypur dest Path
    File externalStoragePublicDirectory = new File(destPath);
    if (!externalStoragePublicDirectory.exists() ? externalStoragePublicDirectory.mkdir() : true) {
        String yourRealPath = "YOUR INPUT PATH";//getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedVideoUri); 
        String filePrefix = yourRealPath.substring(yourRealPath.lastIndexOf("."));
        String destFileName = "cut_video";
        boolean isFastMode = false;
        File dest = (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv")) ? new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + ".mp4") : new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + filePrefix);
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dest.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dest = (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv")) ? new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + fileNo + ".mp4") : new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, destFileName + fileNo + filePrefix);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: startMs: " + startMs);
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: endMs: " + endMs);
        filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();
        final String[] complexCommand = isFastMode ?
                (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv") || filePrefix.equals(".m4v") || filePrefix.equals(".mov")) ?
                        new String[]{"-ss", "" + (startMs / 1000), "-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-preset", "ultrafast", "-t", "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000), "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-strict", "-2", filePath}
                        : new String[]{"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-preset", "ultrafast", "-ss", "" + (startMs / 1000), "-t", "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000), "-c", "copy", filePath}
                : (filePrefix.equals(".webm") || filePrefix.equals(".mkv") || filePrefix.equals(".m4v") || filePrefix.equals(".mov")) ?
                new String[]{"-ss", "" + (startMs / 1000), "-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-t", "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000), "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-strict", "-2", filePath} :
                new String[]{"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-ss", "" + (startMs / 1000), "-t", "" + ((endMs - startMs) / 1000), "-c", "copy", filePath};
        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
    }
}
```

where  `execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand)` is

```
 private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);


            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use any FFmpeg library like https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android? or you built the entire FFmpeg on your own?

Comment: @Quantum_VC Only used the android library

Comment: @MuhamedRiyasM does this work for mp4 file formate?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party but this might help people in the future. I encountered a lot of issues using the trimming function within FFMEPG especially when dealing with accuracy and speed. The best solution I found is the command below.

```
-ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:00:00.00 -noaccurate_seek -i input.mp4 -codec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 output.mp4
```

Here's an explanation of what's going on:

- -i: Input file
- -ss: This is placed before the input file as it seeks to this position in the input file for speed.
- -t: The position of where the command is going to cut to.
- -noaccurate_seek: Preserves the the frames between -ss and the next keyframe other wise they are dropped by default.
- -codec copy: This copies the video and audio codecs as they are for speed.
- -avoid_negative_ts 1: Sets the first timestamp as 1 and avoids it becoming a negative
- -The output file is the last part of the command

After testing many commands this was the one that gave the fastest and most accurate results without any black screens, missing frames or taking too long to execute.

Comment: I am getting error in this command, Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -avoid_negative_ts'
     -avoid_negative_ts: Invalid argument

Comment: this solution working well

Answer (score 1):

try:

-y -i -ss 00:00:00.00 input_path -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 00:00:00.00 -strict -2  output_path

> -ss is the starttime and -t the duration. HH:MM:SS.SS

its fast as hell. does the trimming without reencoding

Comment: I tried this one and worked a little better, but I still have problems with some videos, studying a little more, I realized that almost all files that I had this issue, are videos processed by WhatsAPP and not recorded by the user, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you provide some code? you must strictly follow the command line order mentioned above. By the way, which format does the videos have?

Comment: I edited my question with the sorce code and the commands, I added links to the original and for the output files as well. Thank you by your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below ffmpeg command of trim with start and end point

```
fun trim(): Array<String?>{
        val cmdList = ArrayList<String>()
        var cmds: Array<String?>? = null
        try{
            cmdList.add("-y")

            cmdList.add("-ss")
            cmdList.add(startduration.toString())
            cmdList.add("-t")
            cmdList.add(endduration.toString())
            cmdList.add("-i")
            cmdList.add(sourcevideopath)
            cmdList.add("-vcodec")
            cmdList.add("copy")

            cmdList.add("-movflags")
            cmdList.add("faststart")
            cmdList.add("-preset")
            cmdList.add("ultrafast")

            cmdList.add(outputvideopath)

            cmds = arrayOfNulls<String>(cmdList.size)
            cmdList.toArray(cmds)

        }catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return cmds!!
    }
```